# How to attach all the EC2 instances with same role programmatically AWS CLI way?

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, aws-iam-policy

I am trying to tag all the EC2 instances that don't have any role to be attached to an existing role. Is there an AWS CLI for it? So, far I am trying with boto3 with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import boto3


ec2_list = ['instanca_1','instanca_2']

for ec2_instance_id in ec2_list:
    client = boto3.client("ec2")
    response = client.associate_iam_instance_profile(
        IamInstanceProfile={
             "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::AWS-ACCOUNT:instance-profile/SSMInstanceProfile",
            "Name": "SSMInstanceProfile",
        },
        InstanceId=ec2_instance_id,
    )

    print(response)
```

Above code snippet worked perfectly as per my need. I don't think AWS CLI has looping functionality like for or while.